# What's the remainder when $x^{7} + x^{27} + x^{47} +x^{67} + x^{87}$ is divided by $x ^ 3 - x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

What's the remainder when $x^{7} + x^{27} + x^{47} +x^{67} + x^{87}$ is divided by $x ^ 3 - x$ in terms of $x$?I tried factoring $x$ from both polynomials but I don't know what to do next since there'd be a $1$ in the second polynomial.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Arthur Yeah sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: Do you already know modular arithmetic or congruences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modulo $x^3-x$ we have $x^3=x$ so $x^{2n+1}=x$ for any integer $n\ge 0$ (a trivial induction exercise). Hence your sum leaves remainder $5x$.

Comment: @OP Note that the above claim requires rigorous *proof* (e.g. by induction). More generally $\,xf(x^2) \bmod x^3\!-\!x\,=\, xf(1)\,$ by modular arithmetic - as in my answer (there the induction is hidden in the application of the  [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)). $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 6):

Let your $87$-th degree polynomial be $P(x)$. You're to find $Q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where
$$
P(x)=(x^3-x)D(x)+Q(x).
$$
Then:
$$
5=P(1)=0\cdot D(1)+Q(1)\implies Q(1)=5;\\
0=P(0)=0\cdot D(0)+Q(0)\implies Q(0)=0;\\
-5=P(-1)=0\cdot D(-1)+Q(-1)\implies Q(-1)=-5.
$$
From $Q(0)=0$, it is easy to see $c=0$. Using this and the other 2 conditions, we have:
$$
a+b=5,\quad a-b=-5\implies a=0,\quad b=5.
$$
In sum $Q(x)=5x$.

Comment: Why must $Q(x)$ be quadratic?

Comment: $Q(x)$ can at the most be a quadratic. But owing to the conditions turns out to be linear.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Because we're dividing by $x^3-x$, a 3rd-order polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

$xf(x^2)\,\bmod\, x(x^2\!-\!1)\, =\, x\,(\overbrace{f(\color{#c00}{x^2})\,\bmod\, x^2\!-\!1}^{\color{#c00}{\Large x^2\ \equiv\,\  1}})\, =\, xf(\color{#c00}{ 1})\, =\, 5x$

Comment: We applied $\ \large hf\bmod hg = h\,(f\bmod g),\, $ the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), to factor out $\, h = x\ \ \ $

Comment: And we used   $\large \bmod x^2\!-\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}{x^2})\equiv f(\color{#c00}1)\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$$ P(x)=x^{7} + x^{27} + x^{47} +x^{67} + x^{87}=x(x-1)(x+1)q(x) + r(x)$$

Note that we have $r(1)= P(1)$, $r(0)= P(0)$ and $r(-1)=P(-1)$.

We can find $$r(x)=x^2+ax+b =5x $$ using the above information.

Answer (score 0):

Doing long division:
$$P(x)=\frac{x^{7} + x^{27} + x^{47} +x^{67} + x^{87}}{x^3-x}=\frac{x^{86}+x^{66}+x^{46}+x^{26}+x^6}{x^2-1}=\\
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{9}(x^{86-2i}-x^{84-2i})+2\sum_{i=0}^{9}(x^{66-2i}-x^{64-2i})+3\sum_{i=0}^{9}(x^{46-2i}-x^{44-2i})+4\sum_{i=0}^{9}(x^{26-2i}-x^{24-2i})+5\sum_{i=0}^{2}(x^{6-2i}-x^{4-2i})+5}{x^2-1}=\\
Q(x)+\frac{5}{x^2-1}=Q(x)+\frac{5x}{x^3-x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^{2n}\equiv1 \pmod{x^2-1}$ so $(x^2-1) | (x^{2n}-1)$ so $(x^3-x) | (x^{2n+1}-x)$

so $x^{2n+1}\equiv x \pmod {x^3-x}$

so $x^7+x^{27}+x^{47}+x^{67}+x^{87}\equiv 5x \pmod {x^3-x}$

Comment: @OP Above is essentially the modular proof in my answer with the modular language (congruences) eliminated, i.e. expressed in the more primitive language of *divisibility*. When learning modular arithmetic you may find it instructive to go back-and-forth between both languages to better understand their relationship.

Comment: i.e. the first 2 lines show $\,\large xf(x^2) \equiv xf(1)\, \pmod{\!x^3\!-\!x}\ $ for special case $\large \,f = x^n\ \  \ $